# Как задать нужный тип в TS

Tags: typescript, typescript-типы

```
class El { };

interface Impure { 
     __value__:any
}

type Box = El | Impure;

function walk(childs:Box[]) { 

    var child: Box;
    for (var i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) { 
         child = childs[i];
         if (child.__value__) { // Error ( Property '__value__' does not exist on type Box)
        // Property '__value__' does not exist on type El 

        }
    }
 }
```

тип Box определяется как El или Impure, да в El свойство '**value**' Нету, но поэтому и ставится условие if, но TS пишит error, не смотря на if.
Интересно как решаются подобные вещи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если не путаю, врсии так с 2.9 появились вот такие функции

```
type Some = any;
const isSome = (q: any): q is Some => true
```

- User-Defined Type Guards - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards

в вашем же примере оно будет так

```
class El { qqp: any }
interface Impure { __value__: any }
type Box = El | Impure;

const isImpure = (q: any): q is Impure => '__value__' in q
const isEl = (q: any): q is El => q instanceof El

function walk(childs: Box[]) {
    var child: Box;
    for (var i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
        child = childs[i];
        test1: {
            if (isImpure(child)) {
                child.__value__
            } else {
                child.qqp
            }
            // child.qqp // err
        }
        test2: {
            if (isEl(child)) {
                child.qqp
            } else {
                child.__value__
            }
            // child.qqp // err
        }
        test3: {
            if (!isEl(child)) break test3;
            child.qqp // is OK

    }
}
```

в прочем сегодня и такие конструкции TS понимает

```
class El { qqp: any }
interface Impure { __value__: any }
type Box = El | Impure;

function walk(childs: Box[]) {
    var child: Box;
    for (var i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
        child = childs[i];
        test4: {
            if ('__value__' in child) {
                child.__value__
            }
        }
    }
}
```

а раньше писали так `(child as Impure).__value__`

```
class El { qqp: any }
interface Impure { __value__: any }
type Box = El | Impure;

function walk(childs: Box[]) {
    var child: Box;
    for (var i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
        child = childs[i];
        test5: {
            if ('__value__' in child) {
                (child as Impure).__value__
            }
        }
    }
}
```