# Работа с элементами формы в typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Только начал разбираться в том как работать в связке react + typescript и уже назрел один вопрос) Существует компонент **Login** в котором есть форма авторизации. На событие **onSubmit** я хочу выбрать из этой формы поля email и password при помощи этого выражения **event.target.elements**. Но typescript ругается и выдает такую ошибку Property 'elements' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'. Подскажите пожалуйста как мне можно исправить эту ошибку, стоит просто написать вместо (event: React.FormEvent) это (event: any) или есть другой способ?

```
interface LoginProps {
 history?: {}
}
const Login: React.FC<LoginProps> = ({ history }) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<Boolean>(false);

  const handleLogin = useCallback(async (event: React.FormEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const { email, password } = event.target.elements;

  }, [history]);

  return (
    <>
        <div className="auth">
      <form className="auth_form" onSubmit={handleLogin}>
        <div className="auth_in">
          <h5 className="title offset_mod">Log In</h5>
          <div className="auth_body">
            <div className="auth_w_input">
              <input
                type="text"
                className="input"
                name="email"
                placeholder="Email"
                aria-label="email"
                aria-describedby="addon-wrapping"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="auth_w_input">
              <input
                type="password"
                name="password"
                className="input"
                placeholder="Password"
                aria-label="password"
                aria-describedby="addon-wrapping"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="auth_footer">
            <button type="submit" className="btn primary_state btn_auth">Log In</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

    </>
```

Comment: `(e.target as HTMLFormElement).elements`, но я не уверен, насколько это best practices. То есть кастинг к форме. Но это точно сработает :) Можно это всё в ифчик обернуть, в которо проверять наличие формы в доме, чтобы уже точно не облажатсья.

Comment: @AlexSazonov спасибо большое за ответ, теперь я получаю те данные что надо, но только если просто присваиваю их в переменную. Но деструктуризацию я не могу сделать, пишет такую ошибку https://prnt.sc/r3d47h можете пожалуйста подсказать как и эту проблему можно решить?)

Comment: Так а деструктуризация и не получится. Это ж не объект. Это массив. Даже не массив, а коллекция. Чтобы с ней как с массивом работать, надо к массиву привести сначала. То есть это будет что-то вроде `let elementsArray = Array.from((e.target as HTMLFormElement).elements)`. но опять же, это не объект. Это массив. То есть чтобы получть какой-то элемент, придётся работать как с массивом. Например `const mailInput = elementsArray[0]`, ну это условно, я не знаю какая там у тебя форма. Хотелось бы, конечно, по красоте, но не выйдет :)

Comment: @AlexSazonov понял спасибо. Возможно в этом случае тогда будет лучше просто через useRef сохранить эти инпуты и потом брать с них значение?
`const emailInput = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);
 const passwordInput = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);
`

Comment: А вот тут не скажу. Я в реакт не умею :)

Comment: @AlexSazonov понял, спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как задать нужный тип в TS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078830/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf-%d0%b2-ts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TS и типы

```
T1: {
    const isForm = (q: any): q is HTMLFormElement => q instanceof HTMLFormElement
    const foo = (e: Event) => {
        if (isForm(e.target)) {
            const { } = e.target.elements;
        }
    }
}
```

```
T2: {
    interface $elements {
        email: HTMLInputElement;
        password: HTMLInputElement;
    }
    const foo = (e: Event) => {
        if (e.target) {
            const form = e.target as HTMLFormElement
            const { email, password }: $elements = form.elements as any;
        }
    }
}
```

### React

работу с формами в реакте оставлю за рамками ответа

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ, ваш способ мне гораздо больше нравится чем мой с использованием useRef в реакте)

Comment: https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/forms